# Rails 4 Engine: Method on Eigenclass of Module not found

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have updated my mountable engine from Ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.2 to Ruby 2.0.0 / Rails 4. Now I am having a strange problem with my namespaced models. It can't find the correct table name. I've figured that the reason for this is a problem with the tabele_name_prefix method on the parent module. It can't be found.

```
module DynaState::AttributeAccessors
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'dyna_state_attribute_accessors_'
  end

  def self.foo
    'bar'
  end
end
```

If I test this in the rails console:

```
2.0.0p0 :004 > DynaState::AttributeAccessors.table_name_prefix
NoMethodError: undefined method `table_name_prefix' for DynaState::AttributeAccessors:Module

2.0.0p0 :005 > DynaState::AttributeAccessors.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for DynaState::AttributeAccessors:Module
```

Whereas when I define it on the fly in the console:

```
2.0.0p0 :002 > module Foo; def self.bar; 'argh!' end; end;
2.0.0p0 :003 > Foo.bar
=> "argh!"
```

My guess is that during initialization it is not evaluating all the files that compose the module. Especially not the file where the methods are defined. But I don't know how to fix it or if it is even the problem.

Do you have any Idea how I could debug this or what the problem is?

EDIT: This problem is only occuring with the ONE module. The AttributeAccessors module.

Comment: What is the path to file containing this code? And what is the filename?

Comment: project_root/app/models/dyna_state/attribute_accessors.rb

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call methods on a `Module` until you've `included` or `extended` them in a class, if in your console you do

`extend DynaState::AttributeAccessors`

and then

`DynaState::AttributeAccessors.table_name_prefix`

That should most likely do it for you. I'm really not sure but the module defined on the fly in the console might be available/included in the `main` scope of the console context.

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood. This is the rails console, not the plain IRB. It found the module. The module is there. Otherwise I would have gotten a "undefined Constant" error. Or, from another app's rails console:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0bfe5159d139a7afd50

Comment: ok, I think I totally got this wrong, is this happening only for namespaced modules?

Comment: What do you get if you do `DynaState::AttributeAccessors.methods - Object.methods` ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f6548b5b315724f48d1 Here the output. Thanks for the 2nd question. It is not happening with all modules, just with the AttributeAccessors one. Strange.

Comment: very strange infact, your module doesn't contain the method you are calling at all. Hence the `NoMethodError`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I did not see the '-'. I get an empty Array. You don't need to do the substraction though, you can pass "false" to #methods and it will exclude inherited methods.

Comment: Could it be possible that you have the same module defined elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. I have partial definitions of the module in 8 files.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought it is normal that classes that are inside the model are in an extra file, that is the reason why there are so many partial definitions. This, and another module inside that one residing in lib/